# 2009 Kia Spectra P0507 code thrown after alternator replaced at the shop

Tags: alternator, idle, kia, spectra, p0507

Have a Kia spectra, 2009, and just had the alternator replaced at the shop, it started a little hard and idled a little low off the bat, drove it 25 miles home, idle seemed a bit higher than normal and the check engine light came on, code reader says P0507. Any thoughts on what could be going on?

Comment: Welcome to the Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair SE! That code refers to a higher than expected RPM with the Idle Air Control System. Did the shop mess with anything other than the alternator?

Comment: They shouldn’t have messed with anything. Not that I am aware of.  It’s been dying at startup the last few times I’ve driven it today as well.

Comment: Was it dying before the alternator replacement? And did you also replace the battery?

Comment: It was not dying before the alternator replacement, never had a dying problem until now. The battery was not replaced, it was a new 5-year warranty battery just 2 years ago and the battery has had no problems. I may have the battery tested tomorrow at our local auto store just to double check. I would think if the battery wasn’t holding a good charge right now the battery light would come on though.

Comment: The battery light is not a battery condition treter - it just shows that the alternator is putting out sufficient voltage...

Comment: See if any intake related hoses may have been knocked loose or damaged during the alternator replacement.